# Why is my NSIS code not picking up a Registry key?

Tags: registry, nsis

I have been trawling lots of related Qs such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488717/detecting-if-a-program-is-already-installed-with-nsis), but been struggling to get my first NSIS installer up and running.

The installer is specific for 64bit machines (other code captures this and aborts if 32bit).

I just need to return a value of 0 (no install found, 1 (v9 found) or 2 (v10 found).

At the moment, if I run this NSIS on a machine in all three scenarios, it always returns a 0.

**Can someone point me to what I have done wrong in the logic of the code?**
It is also likely that I have not done this in the most elegant of ways, so would really appreciate a snippet of a better approach, ideally with some reasoning.

```
Var AGSv

Section "Check AGS" SEC01  
call CheckAGS
 Pop $R0
 messagebox MB_OK $AGSv 
SectionEnd

;Check to see if AGS is installed, and which version.
Function CheckAGS
        ;This is the key for v10
        ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ESRI\Server10.0\CoreRuntime" "RealVersion"
        ${If} $1 == ""
          GoTo Try931
        ${Else}
          StrCpy $AGSv 2  
        ${EndIf}
        ;This is the key for v9
        Try931:
        ReadRegStr $2 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ESRI\ArcServer\Microsoft .NET Framework Edition" "RealVersion"
        ${If} $2 == ""
          GoTo NoAGS
        ${Else}
          StrCpy $AGSv 1 
        ${EndIf}    
    NoAGS:
    StrCpy $AGSv 0
    Messagebox MB_OK "No AGS installation detected."
FunctionEnd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your goto logic in the function, the `StrCpy $AGSv 0` line always gets executed (And you never push anything so the pop after `call CheckAGS` gets a "random" value)

```
Function CheckAGS
ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ESRI\Server10.0\CoreRuntime" "RealVersion"
${If} $1 != ""
    StrCpy $AGSv 2
    return
{EndIf}
ReadRegStr $1 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ESRI\ArcServer\Microsoft .NET Framework Edition" "RealVersion"
${If} $1 != ""
    StrCpy $AGSv 1
    return
{EndIf}
StrCpy $AGSv 0 ;not found
Messagebox MB_ICONSTOP "No AGS installation detected."
FunctionEnd
```

You should not use Wow6432Node directly, to read from the 64 bit registry use [SetRegView](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#setregview)...

Comment: Works great, and taught me a lesson.  Will look into the SetRegView, as I also read that elsewhere on SE.

Thanks!