# INNO Setup Drivers already installed

Tags: driver, inno-setup

I saw this: [Detecting if a program is already installed with NSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488717/detecting-if-a-program-is-already-installed-with-nsis).

I want to ask the pretty much the same question for Inno Setup 5.

But basically my question is: Is there any way to check if a program (driver) is installed already on the computer so that i skip the install of the drivers from my [run] section?

Comment: You should be able to check for the registry key and use http://www.jrsoftware.org/isfaq.php#conditional

Comment: Or make a [`Check`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptcheck) function in a `[code]` section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to check. How easy depends on what you want to check for.
If the driver package creates a certain registry key then you can use a `Check:` parameter that calls `RegKeyExists` or similar.

The [Upgrades](http://www.vincenzo.net/isxkb/index.php?title=Upgrades) article on the ISXKB wiki gives an example of how to check for entries added to the Add/Remove programs list.