# How to check program is pre-installed or not using nsis?

Tags: nsis

I have created installer for my windows application using NSIS. My program needs some pre-installed applications in client's machine like vc_x86runtime for 2017.

> I am able to install this silently using NSIS:
>
> `execwait "$temp\MyAppPreRequisites\VC_x86Runtime.exe /Q"`

The problem is **I want to check if setup is pre-installed or not**. I have refer this [(detecting-if-a-program-is-already-installed-with-nsis)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488717/detecting-if-a-program-is-already-installed-with-nsis) answer, But I didn't find any registry for VC_x86Runtime.

I also want to do similar operation with

> SharedManagementObjectsx64.msi, SQLSysClrTypes.msi, Crystal11setup.msi

to check their availability in machine as they are also required to pre-installed in client machine.

Comment: You need to look at documentation for *each* of those, and some may not be straightforward (i.e. might be easier and fast enough to always install Visual C++ runtime, but there may be easy markers to check for Crystal Reports and/or it takes long enough you don't want to take the time if it is already there).