# NSIS: How check that application is installed

Tags: nsis, regedit

I need to check if Microsoft filter pack 2.0 application is installed. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488717/detecting-if-a-program-is-already-installed-with-nsis) answer, but in my case I haven't the Application name, instead the name directory with program in registry named as `{95140000-2000-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}` Here is my code to detect for installed app:

```
ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${FILTER_PACK_KEY}" "UninstallString"
IfErrors FilterPackNotFound FilterPackFound
```

Comment: Have you defined FILTER_PACK_KEY? What is the problem, is it not detecting or are you getting false positives?

Comment: @Anders Yes I have a key, but it's not detecting anithing and this code return empty string in messageBox: `ReadRegStr $0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\95140000-2000-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE" "InstallDate" 
 MessageBox MB_OK "NSIS is installed at: $0"`

Comment: this case also doesn't work: `"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{95140000-2000-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}"`

Comment: Is this filterpack 64-bit?

Comment: @Anders yes it is 64-bit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry on 64-bit Windows has [two "views"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog64/registry-redirector) and 32-bit applications access the 32-bit view by default.

NSIS can access the 64-bit view by using the `SetRegView` instruction:

```
Section
SetRegView 64
RegReadStr $0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{95140000-2000-0409-1000-0000000FF1CE}" "UninstallString"
SetRegView 32
MessageBox mb_ok $0
SectionEnd
```